# How to export SQL query results to file in ABAP ADT?

Tags: eclipse, export, opensql, abap-adt

right now I am using Eclipse to do SQL-commands on tables from a SAP HANA Database.
I would like to save these results as csv- or Excel-data.

When I do a Select-Statement I get a result in Eclipse. By right-clicking into it, there is a button called "Export results", but if I hit it, nothing happens.

I am using the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2022-09"-version. To communicate with the HANA-Datebase I use the Plug-In ABAP Development Tools 3.32.

Do any of you know a way of saving these results?

Sincerely,
Julian

Comment: SAP is a software company, not a database software. Maybe you are talking about SAP HANA or Sybase-related database software. Eclipse has many plugins which can be used to run SQL commands from SQL-based databases. Please edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. But is it importat for Eclipse from which the data comes in order to save these results?

Comment: It's up to you to indicate "SAP" or not, but if you want to indicate the SAP software name then indicate it completely. But **what is important is the name of the Eclipse plugin you are using** to view the HANA tables so that people can answer precisely your question.

Comment: Alright. I edited it.

Comment: You can know if it's SAP HANA Studio or ABAP Development Tools by looking at your Eclipse plugins. Search the Web if you don't know where the plugins are shown. If you are unable to find, at least please share a screenshot.

Comment: Done. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I only have ABAP Development Tools 2022-09 = Version : 1.146.0 (data preview 1.149.0). I can see the options "Copy Row" and "Copy all rows" but not "Export results". There is also a Save button to download the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used SQL-Console to run a select statement, and in the `Data Preview` area (table with the results) there is `Save` icon to the right, where it is possible to save the data:

[image: data selection]

I have an ABAP Development Tools 3.34.2 installed, but don't think there should be a big difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After a little bit of clicking into Eclipse this approarch did the job. :D

It seems like there was a problem with my working space. I just needed to delete the project and made a new one.

Comment: Perfect, was nice to help )